# Remove undefined resolved promise from array of promise in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-promise

I am using typescript and I have a scenario where I have an async function which will return me value `string or undefined` when it will be resolved. Prototype of function look like this :

```
const someFunction = async(someParam : string) => Promise<string | undefined>
```

Now I will call this function in another function(`say myFunction`) for some different values and get the promise.

```
const myFunction = async(params : string[]) : Promise<string[]> => {
    const results = params.map(async (param) => {
        const value = await someFunction(param);
        return value;
    });
    return Promise.all(results);
};
```

Here I am getting below error:

```
Type '(string| undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
  Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.)
```

I want to remove those undefined values(this thing can be done using filter) but also I don't want to change my return type of `myFunction`.I want to keep its return type `Promise<string[]>` instead of `Promise<(string | undefined)[]>`. Can someone help me how could I do this?

Update :I have removed undefined values like this :

```
const myFunction = async(params : string[]) : Promise<string[]> => {
    const results = params.map(async (param) => {
        const value = await someFunction(param);
        return value;
    }).filter(value => value!== undefined);
    return Promise.all(results);
};
```

Now I have removed undefined values. But still I am getting the same error which I was previously getting. Typescript is still asking me to change return type of my function from `Promise<string[]>` to `Promise<(string | undefined)[]>`

Comment: So it's fine if the `params` array and the (wrapped) return array of `myFunction` have different lengths? Because that will be the case if you want to filter out `undefined` values. Since you already know that you can use filter to remove the `undefined` values from the array, where are you stuck?

Comment: @FelixKling yes it will be fine if length is different.

Comment: I may be wrong, but removing the `undefined` results *at run time* won't solve your Typescript errors. For that you probably need `.reduce()` instead of `.map()`, at least.

Comment: @FelixKling main problem is typescript is throwing error is that I need to change my return type from {Promise<string[]>} to {Promise<(string | undefined)[]>} which I don't want.

Comment: `Promise<String[]>` is the wrong return type when you are returning `Promise<(string | undefined)[]>`. Either change the return type or filter out `undefined`.

Comment: FWIW, regardless of TS complaining, your `.filter` wouldn't work because `params.map(...)` returns an array of promises and a promise cannot be `undefined`.

Comment: @FelixKling yes I realized it and and followed the solution you provided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you said, `.filter` can be used to remove `undefined` values:

```
const myFunction = async(params : string[]) : Promise<string[]> => {
    const results = await Promise.all(params.map((param) => someFunction(param)));
    return results.filter((r): r is string => r !== undefined);
};
```

However, we need to help Typescript a little bit to understand that the callback filters out `undefined` values, which is what the `r is string` (a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)) is for.

Comment: omg, you are great. thank you so much. It worked. Looks like there are lots of things which I have to learn.